# Square Connect API: How to to partially capture a charge?

Tags: integration, payment-gateway, payment, square-connect

I'm currently working on payments integration on a web app. Going through the API documentation of Square, I've come to understand that we can capture charges and process them after a period of time([delayed capture transactions](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/delayed-capture-transactions)). I need to know if, after capturing a particular amount, is it possible to charge an amount less than the amount specified previously(partial charging) ? This feature is provided by Stripe API [Partial Charging](https://stripe.com/docs/charges#auth-and-capture). Is there a way it can be implemented using Square Connect API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out.
Unfortunately, partially charging a delayed capture transaction isn’t currently available for Square’s API.
We are constantly improving the product based on feedback like this, so I’ll be sure to share your thoughts with the product team.
Definitely let me know if you have additional questions or suggestions.